# Get list of Dates and map values based on Day XSLT2.0/XSLT3.0

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have this scenario wherein:

Need to list the dates between the Start Date and End Date and based on Type being 'Weekly' or 'Bi-Weekly' need to map the Day Nodes (Monday,Tuesday...) to the corresponding dates.

Week1 is the week of StartDate and Week2 is the second week of StartDate (the week after Week1)

If Type is Weekly:
Need to map Day node values from Week1 node to corresponding dates of that week and keep repeating until EndDate

If Type is Bi-Weekly:
Need to map node values from Week1 node and Week2 node for the first two weeks and keep repeating until End Date

StartDate can be any day of the week and not necessarily be on beginning of week (Monday).

Below is my XML:

```
<Data>
    <Root>
        <Type>Bi-Weekly</Type>
        <StartDate>2022-02-22</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2022-12-31</EndDate>
        <Week1>
            <Monday>4</Monday>
            <Tuesday>0</Tuesday>
            <Wednesday>4</Wednesday>
            <Thursday>0</Thursday>
            <Friday>4</Friday>
        </Week1>
        <Week2>
            <Monday>0</Monday>
            <Tuesday>4</Tuesday>
            <Wednesday>0</Wednesday>
            <Thursday>4</Thursday>
            <Friday>0</Friday>
        </Week2>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Type>Weekly</Type>
        <StartDate>2023-02-12</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2023-12-15</EndDate>
        <Week1>
            <Monday>4</Monday>
            <Tuesday>0</Tuesday>
            <Wednesday>4</Wednesday>
            <Thursday>0</Thursday>
            <Friday>4</Friday>
        </Week1>
        <Week2>
            <Monday>0</Monday>
            <Tuesday>4</Tuesday>
            <Wednesday>0</Wednesday>
            <Thursday>4</Thursday>
            <Friday>0</Friday>
        </Week2>
    </Root>
</Data>
```

My desired output for Bi-Weekly is:

```
22-Feb-22|Tuesday|0
23-Feb-22|Wednesday|4
24-Feb-22|Thursday|0
25-Feb-22|Friday|4
28-Feb-22|Monday|0
1-Mar-22|Tuesday|4
2-Mar-22|Wednesday|0
3-Mar-22|Thursday|4
4-Mar-22|Friday|0
.
.
.
20-Dec-22|Tuesday|4
21-Dec-22|Wednesday|0
22-Dec-22|Thursday|4
23-Dec-22|Friday|0
26-Dec-22|Monday|4
27-Dec-22|Tuesday|0
28-Dec-22|Wednesday|4
29-Dec-22|Thursday|0
30-Dec-22|Friday|4
```

My desired output for Weekly is:

```
22-Feb-22|Tuesday|0
23-Feb-22|Wednesday|4
24-Feb-22|Thursday|0
25-Feb-22|Friday|4
28-Feb-22|Monday|4
1-Mar-22|Tuesday|0
2-Mar-22|Wednesday|4
3-Mar-22|Thursday|0
4-Mar-22|Friday|4
7-Mar-22|Monday|4
8-Mar-22|Tuesday|0
.
.
.
19-Dec-22|Monday|4
20-Dec-22|Tuesday|0
21-Dec-22|Wednesday|4
22-Dec-22|Thursday|0
23-Dec-22|Friday|4
26-Dec-22|Monday|4
27-Dec-22|Tuesday|0
28-Dec-22|Wednesday|4
29-Dec-22|Thursday|0
30-Dec-22|Friday|4
```

Additionally . . Getting rid of Dates with value as '0' in the output will help.

The structure of input file can be modified if it will make the process easy such as

```
<Data>
    <Root>
        <Type>Bi-Weekly</Type>
        <StartDate>2022-02-21</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2022-12-31</EndDate>
        <Week>
            <W1Monday>4</W1Monday>
            <W1Tuesday>0</W1Tuesday>
            <W1Wednesday>4</W1Wednesday>
            <W1Thursday>0</W1Thursday>
            <W1Friday>4</W1Friday>
            <W2Monday>0</W2Monday>
            <W2Tuesday>4</W2Tuesday>
            <W2Wednesday>0</W2Wednesday>
            <W2Thursday>4</W2Thursday>
            <W2Friday>0</W2Friday>
        </Week>
    </Root>
</Data>
```

Thanks!

Current Code : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVb7/4

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Hey Michael . . I have been trying to get this work and looked up several other posts as well and was able to come up with code which is generating the date list but am blank on how to proceed with mapping based on the Day nodes. I did not post my code since I wasn't sure if it will help or rather may confuse others. Please find a quick look of my current code at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVb7/2 My intent was not to get my code wrriten by others, apologies if it seemed otherwise. Fairly new to posting questions.

Comment: I don't get what you are looking for, if you want to map the day nodes from the input to dates and your sample input has no Saturday nor Sunday, why does your desired output have `Saturday`s nor `Sunday`s? As for the code you have linked to, consider to include it in the question. If the format in your input is e.g. `2022-02-21` it seems you can just feed those values to the `xs:date` constructor to have XSLT/XPath `xs:date` values you can do date/duration arithmetic with. So why that `mf:createDate` function seeming designed for a different input format?

Comment: Hi Martin, I do not need the weekends on the output, had mentioned it at the end of the post but it was confusing and I have removed it from desired output. As for the date, I was actually referring to your code on another question (https://cutt.ly/lPSGdsL) and had left it as such but have now updated the same in my xsltfiddle with xs:date but am not clear on how to proceed further. This post (https://cutt.ly/lPSGdsL) seemed kind of close to my need but am still stuck as for my requirement. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hi Martin, I do not need the weekends on the output, had mentioned it at the end of the post but it was confusing and I have removed it from desired output. As for the date, I was actually referring to your code on another question (cutt.ly/lPSGdsL) and had left it as such but have now updated the same in my xsltfiddle with xs:date but am not clear on how to proceed further. This post (cutt.ly/lPSGdsL) seemed kind of close to my need but am still stuck as for my requirement. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this can help:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="week1" match="Week1/*" use="name()" />
<xsl:key name="week2" match="Week2/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="startDate" select="xs:date(StartDate)" />
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="(xs:date(EndDate) - $startDate) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')" />
    <xsl:for-each select="0 to xs:integer($n)">
        <xsl:variable name="week2" select=". idiv 7 mod 2" />
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="$startDate + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * ." />
        <xsl:variable name="day-of-week" select="format-date($date, '[F]')" />      
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="key(if ($week2) then 'week2' else 'week1', $day-of-week, $root)" />      
        <xsl:if test="$value > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date($date, '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]'), $day-of-week, $value" separator="|"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This needs adjustment to accommodate `<Type>Weekly</Type>` - but that shouldn't be too difficult. Also, if I am not mistaken, it assumes that `StartDate` is always a Monday.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVb7/5

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your input. This is producing the results and am trying to understand the logical processing of the code and flow. Checking to see how it fits into my code and testing around <Type>Weekly</Type> but the StartDate may not be necessarily on a Monday or beginning of the week and  can be from any day of the week.

Comment: Then we would need an exact definition of "first week": is it the first 7 days beginning with StartDate, or is it a calendar week starting on Monday or Sunday. If it's the latter, then this adds a sizable complication to the problem. Probably worth a separate question since this one is already combining several issues.

Comment: Understandable. As for "First Week", it would denote the week in which the Start Date falls. If the StartDate is 24-Feb-2022(Thursday), then the week of 21-Feb-22 (Monday) to 27-Feb-22(Sunday) needs to be considered as the First Week and the next week of 28-Feb-22(Monday) to 06-Mar-22(Sunday) needs to considered as the Second Week and mapping would have to be accordingly 

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You will need to "shift" the calculation of `$week2` based on the day-of-week of StartDate.

Comment: As advised, I have posted a new separate question highlighting the scenario while am trying to still understand the logic and code rather than just reusing it. Detailed Question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228587/map-value-against-dates-based-on-day-and-week-xslt2-0-xslt3-0

Comment: I suggested posting a separate question focusing on the "shifting" problem. You have reposted this question in its entirety - and I expect it will be closed as a duplicate.